# Magento 1.9 PHP7 Mysql repair

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I know Magento 1.9 does not support php 7 however is there any version of the Magento database repair tool that would work with Magento 1.9 on php 7 server? I believe our magento database is corrupt and until we migrate to 2.2 we need to fix this current sites database.

Comment: do you have acces to mysql? can you check what exactly broken? run mysql check

Comment: I have access to mysql via the mysql workbench utility. However not sure how to run the mysql check command?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-develop-object-management-inspector.html

Answer (score 0):

You can repair magento database with database repair tool.

this tool is provided by magento so it is authenticate to use

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html

Comment: Murtuza I have read that http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html will not work on a php7 server?